# Tailing a logfile and processing each line is missing data when converting a file with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, tail

I am running a script to tail a log file as per the code snippet below. I am running into a problem where by the line passed into $line is missing a number amount of bytes from the beginning when several lines are written to the log file at nearly the same time.

I can check the file afterwards and see that the offending line is complete in the file so why is it incomplete in the script. Some kind of buffering issue perhaps?

The processing can sometimes take several seconds to complete would that make a difference?

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -F /var/log/mylog.log | while read line
do
   log "$line"
   ffmpeg -i "from.wav" "to.mp3"
done
```

Full line in file

```
"12","","765467657","56753763","test"
```

example logged $line

```
657","56753763","test"
```

**Update**
I have done some more debugging of my code and it seems the processing that is causing the problem is a call to ffmpeg used to convert a wav to mp3. If I swap that with just a sleep then the problem goes away. Could ffmpeg effect the buffer somehow?

Comment: My guess is that `tail` writes full lines with a single call to `write`, but that doesn't mean there is enough room in the pipe buffer to hold the whole line, so the shell has to discard something to make room. It appears the `write` only blocks if the buffer is completely full when it starts.

Comment: Each line is only about 300 bytes each and this happens when only 3 or 4 lines are written at once would that be enough to fill the pipe buffer?

Comment: Hm, probably not. `ulimit -p` suggests `bash` may cap the pipe size at 4096 bytes, and I think Linux itself uses 64K (confirmed for my with the script from [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11954/22257)).

Comment: try the next: `tail -F /var/log/mylog.log | grep --line-buffered '.' | while ...`

Comment: many thanks for the suggestion but it did not make a difference. I have updated the question with some more information

Comment: `ffmpeg` reads from std input in a while loop. To avoid it, redirect ffmpeg's std input to another source, say `/dev/null`, so your ffmpeg lines looks like: `ffmpeg -i "from.wav" "to.mp3" < /dev/null`

Comment: @lind That fixed it! I take it ffmpeg somehow moves the buffer on a few bytes. Thank you so much. Please add an answer and I'll mark it correct

Comment: updated question to include ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `while` loop `ffmpeg` reads from `std input`, consuming all the arguments at once. To prevent this behavior a common workaround is redirecting `ffmpeg`'s `std input` to `/dev/null`, as shown below:

```
tail -F /var/log/mylog.log | while read line
 do
   log "$line"
   ffmpeg -i "from.wav" "to.mp3" < /dev/null
done
```

There are also other commands, such as `ssh, mplayer, HandBrakeCLI` ..., that display the same behavior in a while loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a platform with a reasonably recent version of [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) (e.g. any fairly recent *Linux* distro), you can use [`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#stdbuf-invocation) to force line buffering.

The example in the [`stdbuf` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) is highly relevant:

```
 tail -f access.log | stdbuf -oL cut -d ' ' -f1 | uniq
```

This will immedidately display unique entries from access.log

Comment: This "cut -d aq aq ..." has puzzled me for a moment, wondering whether this was an undocumented "cut" hack. Moreover, this very command line has been widely copy-pasted all over the internet.
Turns out that linux.die.net had a bug while turning the text documentation into HTML, and these 'aq' used to be single quotes in the text version of the manual.
The actual example is then `tail -f access.log | stdbuf -oL cut -d ' ' -f1 | uniq`

Comment: I honestly don't even remember writing this answer. I guess I must've copy-pasted it without paying attention. I just went and edited it and it seems fine now.